# Display content of file in UI using SWT

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, widget

I have created a Client application using SWT. Currently im facing this problem, I want to display the contents of log file using SWT something like the Console in Eclipse or tail in Linux terminal which updates continuously. Is this possible? If yes what should I be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [LogViewer](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/logviewer/) plugin it is doing what you describe

Comment: I implemented using Apache tailer, I did not know about this, so had to write some hacks, will try this one, thanks!

Comment: Im creating a custom tool so is it possible to use Log Viewer for that? Or is it just an eclipse plugin?